# Use cases for chi square goodness of fit tests

Tags: goodness-of-fit

In the answer to the question: [Chi squared goodness of fit test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138235/chi-squared-goodness-of-fit-test), user [glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/805/glen-b) comments that:

> The circumstances where it really makes much sense to formally test goodness of fit are surprisingly few.

Perhaps the reason for this that in a lot circumstances, there are better options. However, the one-sample multinomial model appears theoretically appealing, so I wanted to understand:

> When *does* it make sense to practically use the goodness of fit test?

For example a possible use case could be to test (lack of) fit in a logistic model when the cell counts are not too low. However, I have doubts about this. In truth, the few examples like this that I came up with have possibly better alternatives, hence my question.

*edit:* I'd like to add that if this question does not have a good answer then one wonders why this topic is routinely taught at the undergrad level - even to people who take only one statistics course in college.

Comment: Big-list questions rarely fit the SE model.  We have allowed them primarily for requests for references and educational materials, which we make CW.